# Angular, not able to redirect to another web page

Tags: html, css, angular

first of all thank you very much for taking the time to read this consultation. I'm new to angular development, I found it interesting to learn about this technology and not use the frameworks I've been using for some time. Currently I'm developing a very simple web application, the problem I have is that when I click on the "Login" link absolutely nothing happens. It also doesn't show me an error message. I copy the code that I currently have. I thank you if you could help me with this problem.

app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            ....
            <li class="nav-item">
                <!-- <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/login']">Iniciar Sesión</a> -->
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Iniciar Sesión</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

// used to create fake backend
import { fakeBackendProvider } from './_helpers';

import { appRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { JwtInterceptor, ErrorInterceptor } from './_helpers';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { LoginComponent } from './login';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register';
import { AlertComponent } from './_components';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        appRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        AboutComponent,
        TeamComponent,
        ServiceProvidedComponent,
        ContactComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        AlertComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },

        // provider used to create fake backend
        fakeBackendProvider
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { };
```

app.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from './_services';

@Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
export class AppComponent {
    currentUser: any;

    constructor(private router: Router, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
        this.router.errorHandler = (error: any) => {
          this.router.navigate(['404']); // or redirect to default route
          };
        this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(x => this.currentUser = x);
    }

    logout() {
        this.authenticationService.logout();
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
}
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { LoginComponent } from './login';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register';
import { AuthGuard } from './_helpers';

const routes: Routes = [
    // { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },

    // otherwise redirect to home

    // { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const appRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to show the rendered views.
So your code should be

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            ....
            <li class="nav-item">
                <!-- <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/login']">Iniciar Sesión</a> -->
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Iniciar Sesión</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it was that.